# Why was my flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flagging, not-an-answer

I flagged an [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37424/what-is-yaaleh-veyavo-about/45598#45598) as NAA and while it was deleted by a mod, it was marked as "disputed".

If you're going to delete it, shouldn't my flag be helpful?

Comment: I don't understand why that wasn't an answer. It was hard to understand, but it was saying that the strange language of the prayer is due to its history of replacing a different one.

Answer (score 5):

The post was deleted about 2 hours *after* your flag was marked disputed.

It was marked disputed by [Community](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) because [not all the reviewers who reviewed the post recommended deletion.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/13086)

Comment: And a little more generally: moderators don't dispute flags; if a moderator handles it it's either helpful or declined.  "Disputed" means something else happened (from the community).